# OSCAP on Centos 8

Tags: centos8

I am trying to run scap-workbench on Centos 8, but I am not seeing a profile for Centos 8. Is there one somewhere? I have googled scap-workbench centos 8, but have not found any. Has one been created yet, or is there a way that I can convert the RHEL 8 profile to Centos 8?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open bug in the CentOS bugtracker](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16717) and it provides a workaround (if you really need this functionality before it is fixed upstream)